# How to get the product of a vector by reduce in rust?

Tags: rust

I get it that how can I use `fold` to get the product:

```rust
let product = V.iter().fold(1, |res, a| res * a);
```

But I have no idea to get the product with `reduce`. I know that I can use the method `into_iter`:

```rust
let produce = V.into_iter().reduce(|a, b| a * b).unwrap();
```

But `into_iter` will move the owner. If I just use `iter` method, it will raise error...

```
 $ rustc main.rs
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> main.rs:3:42
  |
3 |     let produce = V.iter().reduce(|a, b| a * b).unwrap();
  |                                          ^^^^^
  |                                          |
  |                                          expected `&{integer}`, found integer
  |                                          help: consider borrowing here: `&(a * b)`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
p
```

But when I just take its ref, the rustc tell me that I cannot get the ref of temp value.

Please tell me how to get the answer by `reduce` or why I cannot get the answer by `reduce`.

Comment: what error ????

Comment: @Stargateur , thanks and I update it already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, the correct solution is to copy the values, i.e. dereference them using an adapter such as `Iterator::copied()`. But the underlying issue is worth going into a bit more detail.

`V.iter()` is constrained to leave the vector intact after the iteration is done, so it cannot move the elements from the vector when yielding them. And `Vec::iter()` has to work for all kinds of values, not just numbers, so it cannot copy the elements, or even clone them, because they might not be `Copy` or `Clone`. Instead, `Vec::iter()` yields *references* over elements as stored in the vector, leaving it up to *you* to copy or clone them (or just inspect them without doing either) as you see fit. So in your case `V.iter()` yields *references*  such as `&u32`.

The consequence is that:

- `fold()` works because it uses the type of the inital value (`u32`) as accumulator type. In the closure `|res, a| res * a` the types supplied/expected by `reduce` are `|res: u32, a: &u32| -> u32 { res * a }`. Since `u32 * &u32` gives you an `u32`, the closure body satisfies its signature.
- `reduce()` doesn't work because it takes the item type (`&u32`) as the type of the accumulator. The full signature of `|a, b| a * b` is `|a: &u32, b: &u32| -> &u32 { a * b }`, which doesn't compile because `&u32 * &u32` in the closure body doesn't produce a `&u32` but a `u32`.

Note that you can't fix the `reduce()` variant by writing the closure as `|a, b| &(a * b)`, even though the compiler suggests just that. While that would be correct on the type system level, it would be rejected by the borrow checker. Since Rust has no garbage collector, every reference must point into an owned object that outlives it, and there is no place to store `a * b`. Returing a reference to the temporary value holding the result would cause a dangling reference, as duly noted by the compiler if you try it. (But just for the fun of it, you *could* write `V.iter().reduce(|a, b| Box::leak(Box::new(a * b)))`, which would pass both the type and the borrow checker, at the insane price of heap-allocating *and leaking* each processed number.)

The correct answer fixes the issue by changing all types to `u32`, so the closure passed to `reduce()` becomes `|a: u32, b: u32| -> u32 { a * b }`, which of course compiles.

Comment: Thanks, your kind answer help me a lot to know how rust's iter works!

Answer (score 1):

With `reduce`, you would need to copy them. it should be the same performance as actually using the references:

```rust
fn main() {
    let V = [10, 20, 5, -23, 0];
    
    let res: i32 = V.iter().copied().reduce(|a, b| a*b).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1137ebec629a343f95c43c37662bb39c)